# Why does the following code not work on python2?

Tags: python

The following code works fine on python3 but not on python2? Please help me out. I tried running python3 form terminal. But when I run it through IDE it runs python2 and shows error. It shows error at the statement input().

```
def addItem(listOfItems, itemInTheList):
    listOfItems.append(itemInTheList)


def showItems(listOfItems):
    length = len(listOfItems)-1
    while length >= 0:
        print("{}\n".format(listOfItems[length]))
        length -= 1
        continue


print("Enter the name of Items: ")
print("Enter DONE when done!")

listOfItems = list()

while True:
    x = input(" > ")
    if x == "DONE":
        break
    else:
        addItem(listOfItems, x)


showItems(listOfItems)
```

Comment: Anyway, your code works flawlessly in Python 3

Comment: Ya it works well on python3.. thanks by the way..

Answer (score 1):

`input()` needs to be `raw_input()` for Python 2.

This was documented in the [Python 3 change logs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html):

"PEP 3111: raw_input() was renamed to input(). That is, the new input() function reads a line from sys.stdin and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises EOFError if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of input(), use eval(input())."

Also, as cdarke pointed out, print statements shouldn't have parentheses around the item to print.

Comment: please upvote so that I get 15 reputation and I can upvote your answer

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 `input` is used for a different purpose, you should use `raw_input` in Python 2.

In addition, your `print` should not use parentheses.  In Python 3 `print` is a function whereas in Python 2 it is a statement.  Alternatively:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

In this case you can achieve some portability with something like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Not named on 2.6
    from __future__ import print_function
    userinput = raw_input
else:
    userinput = input
```

Then use `userinput` instead of `input` or `raw_input`.  Its not pretty though, and generally it is best to stick with just one Python version.